# Storing a specific number pattern in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, array-algorithms

I am working on a question and want to generate a specific pattern
which is

```
1000
1100
1110
1111
0100
0110
0111
0010
0011
0001
```

using recursion and a for loop but when I write the code it gives me an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
public class NQueenProblem {
    final static int N = 8;

    void printSolution(int board[][])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                System.out.print(" "+board[i][j]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    void solveNQUtil(int board[][], int col)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            solveNQUtil(board, col + 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NQueenProblem Queen = new NQueenProblem();
        int board[][] = new int[N][N];
        Queen.solveNQUtil(board, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `solveNQUtil` calls itself infinitely.

Comment: @Ruzihm what would you recommend?

Comment: Just to generate the pattern you don't need this code, you can see the right-most bit is going to the left-most position on successive move by inversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a recursive function that prints out as many lines that start with however many zeros and however many columns, and have it call itself with one additional leading zero. Also, keep track of what row is to be edited next.

If the number of leading zeros equals the number of columns, return because you're done:

```
public class NQueenProblem {
    static void printSolution(int board[][])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" "+board[i][j]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }    
    static void solveNQUtil(int leadingZeros, int startingRow, int board[][])
    {
        int columns = board[0].length;

        if (leadingZeros == columns) return;

        for (int ones = 1; leadingZeros+ones <= columns ; ones++) 
        {
            int curRow = startingRow + ones - 1;

            for (int i=0 ; i<ones ; i++) board[curRow][i+leadingZeros] = 1;
        }

        solveNQUtil(leadingZeros + 1, startingRow + columns - leadingZeros, board);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int totalColumns = 4;
        int rows = (int)((totalColumns+1)*totalColumns*0.5); //

        int board[][] = new int[rows][totalColumns];

        solveNQUtil(0, 0, board);
        printSolution(board);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually wanted then to store in a array and further use it

Comment: @Swaraj that would be a good thing to include in an edit to the question

Comment: @Swaraj I don't know if you noticed but I updated this answer to fill out an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome the error by modifying the solveNQUtil method as follows. **It doesn't guarantee that you will get the answer you are looking for.**

```
void solveNQUtil(int board[][], int col)
   {
      if (col == N)
         return;

      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      {
         solveNQUtil(board, col + 1);
      }
   }
```